# MVC 4 Razor View Html.BeginForm() not working properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using MVC 4 razor view. For some reason the Html.BeginForm does not rendered properly. This is the code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(Model.Form.SubmitTo.Split('/')[2], Model.Form.SubmitTo.Split('/')[1], new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, null))
```

The content in Model.Form.SubmitTo is "/DynamicForm/SubmitDynamicForm/". The code is rendered as:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
```

My intention is to write:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitDynamicForm", "DynamicForm", new { ReturnUrl .....
```

and produce:

```
<form action="/DynamicForm/SubmitDynamicForm" method="post">
```

What is wrong with using string.split inside Html.BeginForm?

Comment: Can you show us your model - `Model.Form`? and data in it? Put a debug point and see if data is populating correctly in Model.

Comment: i think issue is in value of Model.Form

Comment: Why can't you add 2 separate properties `ActionName` and `ControllerName` to the model to avoid the splitting ?